# How can I loop through excel pivot slicers using python win32?

Tags: python, excel, winapi, slicers, pythoncom

I am trying to loop through all the slicers and then export it to PDF. I am having trouble looping through the Slicer Items.

I have tried the following,

```
items = ['abs', 'abc', 'abd', 'cdc', 'dvd']

for each in range(0, len(items)):

    itemSlicer = items[each]
    print(itemSlicer )
    workbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_items").ClearManualFilter() 

    workbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_items").SlicerItems().Selected = True

    workbook.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, path + label)
```

I get the error on `workbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_items").SlicerItems().Selected = True`

The error,

```
com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-a48809dba26f> in <module>
      8 
---> 10     workbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_age").SlicerItems().Selected = True
     11 

~\AppData\Local\Temp\1\gen_py\3.8\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9\SlicerItems.py in __call__(self, Index)
     59         # Default method for this class is '_Default'
     60         def __call__(self, Index=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
---> 61         ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(0, LCID, 2, (9, 0), ((12, 1),),Index
     62             )
     63                 if ret is not None:

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024809), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your variable `itemSlicer` is missing from the line throwing the error. It should look like:

```
workbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_items").SlicerItems(itemSlicer ).Selected = True
```